# Twitter Bootstrap's carousel only slides once

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The following code works as expected. That is, it changes automatically every 3 seconds and I can control it with the previous/next buttons. The problem is that it breaks in an unusual way if I add the .slide class to the carousel.

Adding the .slide class makes the slide work only once. I can click the prev/next button and it will slide as expected but then the carousel will freeze. Allowing the auto-next has the same effect (it will slide to the next and then freeze).

Any ideas?

```
#myCarousel.carousel
  .carousel-inner
    .item.active
      = image_tag 'Carousel1.png'
      .carousel-caption
        %h4 First Thumbnail label
        %p Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    .item
      = image_tag 'Carousel2.png'
      .carousel-caption
        %h4 Second Thumbnail label
        %p Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    .item
      = image_tag 'Carousel3.png'
      .carousel-caption
        %h4 Third Thumbnail label
        %p Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
  %a.left.carousel-control{"data-slide" => "prev", :href => "#myCarousel"} ‹
  %a.right.carousel-control{"data-slide" => "next", :href => "#myCarousel"} ›


:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000
    })
  });
```

Comment: try `wrap:true` as well?

Comment: Do you have `bootstrap.min.js` defined (not just `bootstrap-carousel.js`)?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor wrap:true didn't help.

Comment: @mccannf I only reference bootstrap.min.js as it already contains bootstrap-carousel.js

Comment: Did you use the standard bootstrap.min.js, and not a customised version? It should contain bootstrap-transition.js

Comment: Standard. The thing is that the first slide movement works fine. It just doesn't work after that.

Comment: Anything in the JavaScript console? It sounds like the javascript is failing for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading the transition module and that all the files you are loading have the same version (if are loading bootstrap components separately)